# Array is ignoring Null as a value

Tags: java, arrays, null, nullpointerexception

I have the code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
    if (directory[i].contains (number)) {
        if (directory[i+1] == null){
            directory[i] = null;
        }
        else {
            for (int k=i; k<directory.length; k++){
                System.out.println(directory[k]);
                System.out.println(directory[k+1]);
                if (directory[i+1] != null){
                    directory[k] = directory[k+1];
                    System.out.println(directory[k]);
                }
```

The important bit i think is "if (directory[i+1] != null){" what i am using is an array and i am trying to find if the next element is not null then do the code. However, even if the next value is null it does it anyway. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: This is an `i`-versus-`k` typo issue.

Comment: Sorry for not making the question clear, I have fixed the question now :)

Comment: I think you'd get an array index out of range error on the last iteration of the `i` loop, no?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do, and what is it not doing as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using the loop-index in your loop. You're only testing the *initial* value, over and over again.

This

```
if (directory[i+1] != null){
```

should be this

```
if (directory[k+1] != null){
```

Answer (score 1):

the next value of directory[i+1] is never going to be null @"if (directory[i+1] != null){" because before the else statment you check to see if directory[i+1] == null

my guess is a small typo in iteration maybe you ment directory[k+1]?